# How to get initial cursor position on right of displayed text

Tags: android

This should be simple but I have tried about a dozen things here in stackoverflow on the topic and they either do nothing or crash.

I have a edittext field that starts with the last entry, like "12" and I want the initial cursor to be to the right of the 2 and it always starts to the left of the 1.  That would be fine if there was a del key but with only a back key on the keyboard, the user must manually re-position the cursor before typing over the old text.  There are several fields and he most likely wants to leave most of them alone.  What I want if he wants to just edit the second field to have him hit "next" "bs", "bs", "45", "next", "done".  this way he doesn't have to position the cursor at all.

------------UPDATE----------------------

Here is the main file

```
package com.example.test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static EditText edit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        edit.setSelection(edit.getText().toString().length());
    }
}
```

and here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="12"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/textView4"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit"
    android:text=":"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="00"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setSelection()` on each EditText in `onCreate()`:

```
edit.setSelection(edit.getText().toString().length());
edit2.setSelection(edit2.getText().toString().length());
```

The cursor will still respect the user's touch gestures, but trackball and other movements methods will start with the cursor on the right.

Comment: Of course it crashes, you forgot to initialize `edit` with: `edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);` :) And I don't think `edit` should be static since it is of no use outside this class.

Comment: I modified my code above to include the missing code (at least I think it is correctly placed now) but it still crashes. :-(

Comment: So close! You must call `setContentView()` before `findViewById()`. `findViewById()` can only locate Views that are currently displayed... Simply switch the order of those two lines.

Comment: This is the line that crashes it edit.setSelection(edit.getText().toString().length()); and even changeing it to something simple like edit.setSelection(0); still crashes.

Comment: Something else is up, post your LogCat errors. I noticed your a referencing a TextView that doesn't exist: `android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"`...

Comment: I clicked "clean" on the project and now it runs.  I don't know why that happens with Eclipse but it works now.  Thank you so much for sticking with me.

Comment: No trouble. Though this was the first answer I thought of when I read your problem, I actually found a great place for this answer in my own code. I wouldn't have thought of "improving" my project otherwise, but the workflow seems more natural with it. So, thank you too.

Comment: edit is of the wrong type. Use findById to get the EditText view type. Then have Editable editable = edit.getText(), then set position on editable editable.setSelection().

Comment: @Andrew There are multiple [`setSelection()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection%28int%29) methods, including the one used above in `EditText`, however I don't see one listed under [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html)'s documentation...

Comment: @Andrew My point exactly, that is the _Selection_ class. `editable.setSelection()` won't compile, yet my code will and it answers the question. ... Good luck with learning Android!